# Symbol Suffixes with AlphaVantage

Tags: api, alpha-vantage

I'm not able to find documentation for different symbols and exchanges, I was able to figure out that TSE or TSE work as a suffix for Canadian Exchanges. I'm just wondering how to retrieve prices for the following security: https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=AW.UN ?

I've tried multiple variations of:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?
function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY
&symbol=TSX:AW.UN
&apikey=MYKEY
```

Encoding the period - didn't work.

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?
function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY
&symbol=TSX:AW%2EUN
&apikey=MYKEY
```

Moving the suffix - didn't work

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?
function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY
&symbol=TSX:UN:AW
&apikey=MYKEY
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing around with the search symbol api I used the following query to figure it out:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?
function=SYMBOL_SEARCH
&keywords=Revenue%20Royalties
&apikey=MYKEY
```

Which returned:

```
    {
        "1. symbol": "AW-UN.TRT",
        "2. name": "A&W Revenue Royalties Income Fund",
        "3. type": "Equity",
        "4. region": "Toronto",
        "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
        "6. marketClose": "16:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
        "8. currency": "CAD",
        "9. matchScore": "0.6800"
    },
    {
        "1. symbol": "AW_U.TRT",
        "2. name": "A&W REVENUE ROYALTIES INCOME FU",
        "3. type": "Equity",
        "4. region": "Toronto",
        "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
        "6. marketClose": "16:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
        "8. currency": "CAD",
        "9. matchScore": "0.6800"
    }
```

Comment: do you know why it sends the 1. or 2. ?